# magento show filters in toolbar

Tags: magento-1.8, toolbar

I would like to show the brand, discount and category filters in the toolbar. I want to show it like this - Sort by - category - Brand - Discount - in the toolbar above the category products. Please help me i am a new to magento. I tried to echo filter.phtml in toolbar.phtml and list.phtml but it doesn't seems to pick the code, tried to change it through xml but no help at all. I don't know what else to do, please help. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

The sort by attributes are built in the function `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Config::getAttributesUsedForSortBy`. What happens here is that the attributes are selected from the table `eav_attribute` with a join on the `catalog_eav_attribute` table.

The key here is that it filters on the table `catalog_eav_attribute` and looks for attributes with the column `used_for_sort_by` set to true.

Answer (score 1):

To add this functionality, you should overwrite `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar` block and `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` model

Click [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-products/sort-show-products-by-sold-quantity-in-magento/) for reference